# When moving from 32bit machine to 64bit I have to uninstall my app

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, ide

So this might sound like a complete and total noob question, but I'm going to ask and see what I find anyway.

I'm working on an Android application using Eclipse IDE.  I have two development machines that I use (one for work, one for home) and one is 64bit while the other is 32bit.  The phone that I'm using to test my application is a Google Nexus (Verizon flavored, most up to date drivers).  If I build and run the application using one machine, then try to do the same on the other machine I get a console error that tells me to run an ADB command to uninstall my app because the signature has changed.

From what I understand it's because "debug.keystrore" (located in %USER_HOME%/.android) is different for each machine.  Why does it do this?  I assumed that the application signature was unique to the app not the app + dev machine.  Is this normal behavior?  If so, is there something I can do to get around it?  I'm worried that copy/pasting the file between machines could cause problems, so I haven't tried it yet.  Would I have to move this file every time I switch machines?  Also, if I release my app into the wild; then loose my computer and have to start using a new computer (thus, changing the application sig) will everyone who installed my app have to uninstall the app because the application sig is different?

Bonus round: is there some way I can configure my IDE so that I don't have to change where eclipse looks to find the SDK every time I switch machines (i.e. make it look in both the ProgramFiles directory and the ProgramFiles (x86) directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make sure the app was built by the same developer, Android wants the signature to be the same.  Feel free to copy your debug key between machines.  It has nothing to do with your machine or whether it's 32/64 bit; it only proves that you're the same developer.

When it comes time to release your app, you want to be very careful to

1. Keep your release key private, and
2. Keep your release key backed up in several places.

If you ever lose your release key, you won't be able to update your app, as you suspected.

**Update:** To make my answer more complete, it looks like the way to tell Eclipse which key to use is under Preferences -> Android -> Build.

I use Linux and don't use Eclipse; what I do is just copy `~/.android/debug.keystore` from machine to machine, and the ant build tool uses it automatically, avoiding the pesky "certificates don't match" installation error.

For my release keystore, I have this line in my `ant.properties`:

```
key.store=../private/my-release-key.keystore
```

and keep `my-release-key.keystore` in a private repository much to the same effect.

Comment: Thanks!  I like your answer, but Yury has some (SOME) instructions on a method to fix this issue.  If you don't mind adding some specific instructions for green-horns that stumble across this thread then I would gladly mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that for different platforms Google team has created different debug keys (I guess for tracking purposes). These debug keys do not depend on your application. If you want to distribute your application you need to create your own key. If you sign your application with your own certificate there should not be such kind of problem (because in this case, certificate depends only on attributes that you've entered when you create certificate). Under the Preferences -> Android -> Build you can select which keystore to use.

Comment: Thank you.  The other answers here are good (and dare I say a little more "concise" than your's.  However, you provide some specific instructions.  I can figure things out from here (again, thanks for pointing me in the right direction).

Comment: Just added some more details.

Answer (score 1):

The signature is unique to each of the developers. From what I understand, if you are using the debug key, it uses your mac address or other unique characteristic to create an arbitrary key. So when you build and install your app onto a device with one machine, and then go to use another, you have different signatures, and thus your issue.

To be able to not have this issues, you should create your own key, as others have mentioned, and then use that to sign when you build.

You will NEVER want to release an app with your debug key, this is just for developing and when you go to release your app, you want to use your unique key that you created.

These keys are used to keep others from updating your apps, without your permission, so create a your own dev key and you won't have this issue.

Here is a link that should help you get started and pointed in the right direction: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, with the three comments combined I have a general idea of where to go from here and am sure i can figure it out.  However, I don't feel comfortable marking any answer as correct without there being a little more detail.  Thanks again!

Comment: Well then just upvote them all and call it a day. I also added a link that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've copied "debug.keystore" from one machine to another, there are no ill side-effects.  You can simply overwrite one with the other, and the un-install/re-install problem is fixed.  The debug key is there only to protect the developer's own devices from other developer's binaries.

As others have mentioned, you do not publish your app with the debug key, you must make a release key and sign it, per the instructions on developer.android.com.

Also it's worth noting that the "debug" key is only valid for 1 year from the date it was created (when the SDK was installed).  After a year, the SDK will say it's expired, and generate a new debug key.  You'll have to re-copy the new key to the other machine, and you'll have to un-install the app signed with the old debug key.

As for the other problem you mention, you should have separate Eclipse workspaces that both reference the same Android project, using different SDK locations.  The project does not need to be in a sub-folder of the workspace, so you can make this separation.